# How can I determine which port my GlassFish server is running on?

Tags: windows, glassfish

I have started a GlassFish server on my machine.
How can I determine which port the GlassFish server is running on?
I have tested both 8080 and 4848 ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, it may help

```
asadmin get server | grep listener
```

http://blogs.oracle.com/openroad/entry/changing_default_glassfish_port_numbers

For windows this may help (from the comments of the link)

```
<GLASSFISH_PATH>\\bin>asadmin.bat --port 15050 get server.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.\*
```

Or you can look at the ports from configuration files (in the file search for: ):

```
<GLASSFISH_PATH>\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\config\\domain.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I am running this server on windows